# Display IntegrityError when trying to validate CreateView based on ModelForm using unique_together

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

How would I display an integrity error when using class based view's `CreateView`.

My current Model looks like this :

```
class Delivery(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', editable=False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField('modified', editable=False)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    stream_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    view_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
    jira = models.URLField()
    codereview = models.URLField()
    related_streams = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=sorted(streams()),blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=False,blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

And the corresponding view is :

```
class CreateEntryView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'tracker/entry.html'
    model = Delivery
    success_url = reverse_lazy('table_view')
    status = StreamStatus()
    fields = ['stream_name','view_name','activity_name','jira','codereview','related_streams','description','status']

    def get_initial(self):
        if 'codereview-get' in self.request.GET:
            parsedDict = codereviewParser(self.request.GET['codereview-get'])
            return {'stream_name':parsedDict['stream'].split('_')[1:2][0],
                    'view_name':parsedDict['view'],
                    'activity_name':parsedDict['name'],
                    'jira':parsedDict['jira'],
                    'codereview':self.request.GET['codereview-get'],
                    'description':parsedDict['description'],
                    'status':parsedDict['status']}
        else:
            return self.initial.copy()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_name = self.request.user
        try:
            return super(CreateEntryView, self).form_valid(form)
        except IntegrityError as e:
                messages.error(self.request, "Your data has not been saved!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path)
        return super(CreateEntryView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CreateEntryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['locked'] = self.status.getLocked()
        ctx['unlocked'] = self.status.getUnlocked()
        return ctx
```

I tried a couple of techniques by passing a new context to `render_to_response()` but then I need to pass the entire context again. Also tried `HttpResponse()` which I dont like since it directs me to a blank page with a message. I would like to use an alert message to show the error to the user.

Comment: what about `return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, integritymsg='Your data has not been saved!', reason=whatever))` ? And check and show `integritymsg/reason` in the template.

Comment: Ah that seemed simple. I forgot get_context_data would take **kwargs. That works great. Do you mind posting the answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Is there some place I can see the flow of CreateView. I havee this link but it doesnt give me the flow https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing what `form_invalid` does, but adding your info to the context:

```
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, integritymsg='Your data has not been saved!', reason=whatever))
```

And of course check and show `integritymsg/reason` in the template.

One thing not immediately obvious is that the arguments passed to `get_context_data` are added to the context. All the `get_context_data` being called along the MRO chain add their bit to the context.

ccbv.co.uk is a great tool. Unfortunately you need to inspect the code and find out the flow of execution yourself. It's not complicated, but yes, a diagram would help.
In general, start from as_view, dispatch, get, etc...